# Dynamically creating a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried at [learnpython.org](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Hello%2C_World%21) to create a variable dynamically it can be create as below :

```
food = 'bread'
vars()[food] = 'asdasd'
print (bread)
```

It will print out "asdasd". However when I tried with my python3, it gives me an error (NameError: name 'bread' is not defined). How can I do that using python3?

Comment: This can be done, but it is a *terrible* anti-pattern. If you have to do this, usually something is very wrong with the design.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It works fine for me.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think the OP is saying that he was using the websites built-in Python IDE to run his code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python we tend to avoid this kind of dynamic variables, but anyway your answer is:

```
a = 'test'
globals()[a] = 123
print(test)
```

Better approach is by using a dictionnary.

```
a = 'test'
myVar = {}
myVar[a] = 123
print(myVar['test'])
```

Comment: currently, my issue is I need to read a csv file and based on the user selected columns, I need to create a var to store it. if i ignore this kind of dynamic variables, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The way to do it is to store it in a dictionnary or a list and access it via a key.

Comment: It doesn't work. what I need is i have a variable temp1, storing a value,
temp1 = "country"

i wanted to used that country as a variable for another variable, for example: 
country = "UK"

Comment: @Djangonewbie just use a `dict`